# Adding double values to array list from strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, double

I'm trying to covert an array of strings into an array of doubles.
I'm fairly familiar with ArrayList<>() , but i see there is in an example code give, double[].

example: list = ["1" , "2" , "3"]
desired return: number = [1 , 2 , 3]

```
public double[] ConversionNumber
{
double[] sequence = new double[list.size()];
for(String element:list){
double val = Double.parseDouble(element);
sequence.add(val)}

return sequence;
```

when i do this, i get an error in Bluej compiler: "cannot find symbol- method add(double).

What is a good way to solve this (i'm a beginner at Java).

thanks!

Comment: your `list` is a `List`, not a `array`, right?

Comment: i created list using:

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change your code here

```
for(String element:list){
    double val = Double.parseDouble(element);
    sequence.add(val)
}
```

to this if your `list` is a `List`:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    double val = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i));
    sequence[i]=val;
}
```

if your `list` is an `Array`, then change to this:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    double val = Double.parseDouble(list[i]);
    sequence[i]=val;
}
```

Comment: arrays don't have a `size()` method and they don't have a `get()` method

Comment: @Epicblood Come on, `list` is a `List`, don't you see `list.size()` in his codes? My answer is right absolutely

Comment: "I'm trying to covert an array of strings"

Comment: Looking at the code it might be a `List`, however because he wants the results in an array as well, it's safe to assume that `list` is an array.
He tries to call `add()` on an array, so the `size()` and `get()` may be in error as well.

Answer (score 2):

If `list` is an array, then `list.size()` would fail. I think we can assume it should be a `List<String>`. And you access an array by index. Also, I assume it should be an argument to your method. Next, Java convention for methods names is camelCase.

```
public double[] conversionNumber(List<String> list) {
    double[] sequence = new double[list.size()];
    int pos = 0;
    for (String element : list) {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(element);
        sequence[pos++] = val; // <-- post-increment
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

Comment: The problem is he's calling `add` on an array, not the `list.size()` call based on his error

Comment: im assuming that because he wants a `double[]`, `list` is probably a `String[]` not a `List`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you're working with Collections, you work with collections the whole way. It's bad form to use Lists for one thing, but arrays for another. So it's advisable to do this with a `List<Double>` instead of a `double[]`

```
public List<Double> parseDoubles(List<String> strings) {
    List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<>(strings.size());
    for(String string : strings) {
        doubles.add(new Double(string));
    }
    return doubles;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because arrays dont have an 'add' method. You will want to do something like:

```
double[] sequence = new double[list.length]; 
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    sequence[i] = Double.parseDouble(list[i]);
}
```

If `list` is an actual `List` not a `String[]` as I assumed, you would do:

```
double[] sequence = new double[list.size()]; 
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    sequence[i] = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i));
}
```

Comment: `new double[list.length -1]`, the size of the double[] is not right here.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work for your case:

```
java.util.List<String> list = java.util.Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
public double[] ConversionNumber() {
    double[] sequence = new double[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for(String element:list){
        double val = Double.parseDouble(element);
        sequence[++i] = val;
    }
    return sequence;
}
```